# Java CardLayout events

Tags: java

i have been doing some game programming recently and I am using a CardLayout to switch between different screens (Main Menu, Game Screen, Game Over, etc...)

My question is, every time I switch screens does the previous become "inactive", so lets say I switch from Canvas to Main Menu, are the methods such as pain(), painComponent(), and the game ticks still being called, or is the Canvas "inactive:="

In other words, when I switch would I have to manually stop the game, or does CardLayout do that already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy to test on your own.  Simply put a logging statement in your paintComponent method of the inactive panel and see if it prints when the card is not displayed.

This code shows that it's only calling paintComponent on the first panel:

```
package com.sandbox;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class SwingSandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = buildFrame();
        JPanel cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());

        cards.add(new JPanelThatPrints("1"));
        cards.add(new JPanelThatPrints("2"));
        cards.add(new JPanelThatPrints("3"));

        frame.add(cards);
    }


    private static JFrame buildFrame() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        return frame;
    }


    private static class JPanelThatPrints extends JPanel {

        private String message;

        public JPanelThatPrints(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you :) that answered my question,not sure why I didn't think of doing that before :)